# If $\text{dim}(X)< \infty$ and $\text{dim}(E)=\infty$, then $\text{dim}(E')=\infty$ and $E' \subset X'$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $E=(E,\|\cdot \|_E)$ be a Banach space and $X \subset E$ a closed subspace of $E$. Then $X=(X,\|\cdot \|_E)$ is also a Banach space. Moreover, I know that, the dual of $E$ is cointaned in $X$, that is, $E' \subset X'$ (right?). And if $\text{dim}(X)< \infty$ then $\text{dim}(X')=\text{dim}(X)$. Here, $\text{dim}(X')$ and $\text{dim}(X)$ denote the dimension of $X$ and $X'$, respectively.

**Question.** If $\text{dim}(X)< \infty$  and $\text{dim}(E)=\infty$, then $\text{dim}(E')=\infty$ and $E' \subset X'$?

This seems strange to me, because in this case I would be saying that a space of finite dimension is contained in a space of finite dimension. Or am I thinking something wrong?

Comment: All you have is a map $E'\to X'$ that is the adjoint of the inclusion map $X\to E$. Since $X$ is has the same norm as $E$ this map can be identified with the restriction of functionals and it will be surjective. Hence you don't have $E'\subset X'$.

Comment: And to state explicitly what @s.harp's comment implies, that restriction map can be highly non-injective.

Comment: @s.harp I think that if $X$ is dense in $E$ then (in particular) $E' \subset X'$. Here $X$ and $E$ are Banach spaces such that $X \subset E$. See Exercise $18.6$ in *Nonlinear functional analysis and its applications (2A)-Zeidler, Boron*.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC See comment above.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno: If $X$ is finite-dimensional, then it is complete. In particular, it is closed in any (metric) superspace, so it cannot be dense in $E$, unless $E=X$.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno if $X$ is dense and closed it is all of $E$. The remark about a dense sub-space having a larger dual space requires that $X$ has a different (_finer_) topology than $E$, ie there is some continuous embedding $X\to E$ with dense image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you can think, via restriction, of a functional in $E'$ as a functional on $X$, doesn't mean that there is an inclusion $E'\subset X'$. This can be very easily seen in examples.

For instance let $E=\mathbb C^2$, and $X=\{(a,0):\ a\in\mathbb C\}$. Then $E'=\mathbb C^2$,  where you think of $(c,d)$ as the functional $\langle (c,d),(a,b)\rangle=ac+bd$, and $X'=\mathbb C$. So here $\dim E'=2$, $\dim X'=1$.

Even when both $X\subset E$  are infinite-dimensional, the inclusion $E'\subset X'$ often makes no sense. For instance let $E=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and $$X=\{f\in E:\ f(1)=0\}.$$ Now consider $\phi,\psi\in E'$ be given by
$$
\phi(f)=f(1),\qquad \psi(f)=2f(1). 
$$
Both $\phi$ and $\psi$, which are distinct, are zero when restricted to $X$. In what sense do you want to see them as distinct elements in $X'$? Of course one can create an artificial inclusion (after all, in this example $E=X=E'=X'=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$), but the point is to have an inclusion that is canonical, in which functionals are considered as functionals.

For a more brutal example, let $E=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ and $X=c_0$, the space of sequences that converge to zero. Then $X'=\ell^1(\mathbb N)$, which is separable, while $E'$ is not separable since $E$ isn't. So there is no possible inclusion $E'\subset X'$ as normed spaces, not even an artificial one.

Comment: But if $\text{dim}(E)=\text{dim}(X)= \infty$ then $E' \subset X'$ holds?

Comment: The inclusion does not hold in general, even if you don't take the duals as duals.

Answer (score 1):

A concrete example that $X\subseteq E$ with $\text{dim}(X)<\infty$ and $X^*\subsetneq E^*$ is the following:

Take $E=l_2$ with the usual norm $||.||_2$ given by
$||x||_2=\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|^2\biggr)^{1/2}$, where $x=(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$. Then for $X_m=\{x=(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\in l_2:\ x_k=0\ \text{for all}\ k\geq m+1\}$ we have that $X_m$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^m}$ hence, $X_m^*=\mathbb{R^m}$ whereas $E^*=l_2$.

Comment: I think that if $X$ is dense in $E$ then (in particular) $E' \subset X'$, independent of the dimension of the spaces (see Exercise $18.6$ in *Nonlinear functional analysis and its applications (2A)-Zeidler, Boron*).

Comment: If $X$ is dense in $E$, then the duals are equal.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Even though $ X $ and $ E $ being general Banach spaces, such as $ X \subset E $?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno: have you read the edit to my answer?